# Limiting number of CPU cores used by Python on Unix server

Tags: python, unix, cpu-cores

I am running a Python script to process a large amount of data on a shared Unix computing cluster, with up to 64 CPU cores. I want to make sure that the script runs on only 1 core, but it is using multiple CPU's that I didn't reserve, which interferes with other users of the shared cluster. I have not explicitly put any parallelization in the code, and I am using the resource module for Unix to limit the number of processes created:

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NPROC, (1, 1))
```

However the jobs are still showing 5000% CPU usage or more. How can I force the script to run using a maximum of 1 CPU?
I looked at other possibilities in the resource module, however they all seem to be regarding memory usage or CPU time, not number of cores.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on your code? Some libraries are parallelised/multi-core under the hood. If it's numpy, you might have to explicitly set some properties through numpy.

Comment: I'm using scikit-learn which can be parallelised, but I set the n_jobs parameter to 1 everywhere so it shouldn't create more than 1 job. Otherwise it is just pandas, numpy and scipy, but I couldn't find anything about implicit parallelisation anywhere in the documentation or code. What numpy properties could those be?

Comment: Pandas, numpy, and scipy all use vectorised routines under the hood, most of which are parallelised.

Comment: Sounds like you should research linux cgroups.

Comment: [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716659/taskset-python), another trick CPU usage settings is `APP` level architecture, `OS` forced finished task if starting with full capabilities(Limiting  work on `START` not on `RUN`, you got a lot garbage data if ignore this warning ).