# Assigning taskset to specific Python process (without using PID)

Tags: python, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, cpu, taskset

So I have a Python3 process that needs to be assigned to the 4th CPU core (CPU Affinity 3), currently it's used in 0-2. I added isolcpus=3 to the cmdline.txt in boot and I type the following in terminal:

```
sudo taskset -cp 3 PID
```

The thing is, whenever I close and start the Python script, the PID changes so I'd have to manually find the PID of that Python process and do taskset on it again. Is there a more efficient way for me to automatically start that Python process with the taskset -cp 3 command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend utilizing `psutil` instead. Please see the following answer --

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40856471/13261176

Comment: Thanks! So psutil is not related to isolcpus in the cmdline right?